# Custom Sitecore Form element throws a "null entry for parameter templateId of non-nullable type System.GUID" exception

Tags: sitecore-forms

I'm creating a custom Sitecore Form element of a type of Hyperlink, however when adding this element to a Form it throws an exception:

[image]

Here is a log message:

[image]

What am I missing? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What version do you have of Sitecore?

Comment: Its Sitecore 10.2 XP

Comment: Would you mind adding your code about Hyperlink